# Adding headers in a Spray.io Test Spec fails to send the request into the route

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, spray, spray-test

I'm on Spray 1.3.3. I have a spec that looks like the following:

```
"Add a collection using a PATCH with correct update hash" in {
  Patch("/datastore/collections/FMI", CollectionPatch(addPriceCodes =
    Some(List(PriceCode("AMI", "22", None))))) ~>
    addHeader(hashHeader, updateHash) ~> routes ~> check {
    status should equal(Accepted)
  }
}
```

This looks like it should in the documentation I've seen, and it compiles, but when I run it, I get a 500 back. If I set a breakpoint in the route, I don't ever get inside of it (where I do in other test functions that don't add a header). In IntelliJ I get an error saying it can't resolve the symbol `~>` between the `addHeader` and `routes`.

What's the right way to add in a header to send to the route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I have listed above works fine. I was getting into my route and was looking at the wrong thing in the exception backtrace.